"Connection reset by peer" error when calling Banno token endpoint
Beginning on August 7, 2024 we have noticed an increase in "Connection reset by peer" errors when calling the Banno token endpoint. This appears to be intermittent. Not all users are experiencing this issue and the error will occasionally go away after navigating to the url a few times. For context, we have developed applications for external application buttons through banno olb. A user would click on a button from their online banking portal for something like "Rewards Dashboard" and the link would take them to a url similar to this - {{ specific_subdomain }}.account-hq.com/rewardsDashboard. The "Connection reset by peer" error seems to occur during our attempt to fetch the Banno token on a call similar to this {base url}/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/token
Prior to August 7, 2024 this error hardly ever occurred. We expect that this call for token completes without error. We have tried clearing caches and refreshing our applications and we still see the same error occurring for certain users.

The short answer
The HTTP 411 Length Required error can be fixed by ensuring that you have a Content-Length header with the appropriate content length for any POST or PUT requests.

Content-Length: 0 apparently also works.

The long answer
We switched load balancers around the time noted in your submitted question, and the new load balancers are more strict and require a Content-Length header for requests that have a body.

Thank you for the quick response! In the future, is there anyway that we as a user of Banno integration be notified of these types of changes? Thank you.

In this case, we didn't expect there to be any change due to the load balancers (as a managed service).

Hello, we added the Content-Length header but we are still seeing "Connection reset by peer"' errors. Are there additional steps we can take for troubleshooting?

Which option did you try? There is the option of calculating a Content-Length and providing that number as the value, or (in the edited answer you may not have seen yet) apparently Content-Length: 0 also works.

thanks for the response. We have tried Content-Length: 0 and are still seeing the error occasionally. Follow up question - we were wondering if there have been any changes introduced for rate limiting? And if so, how many requests and for how long before next request?

We haven't published specific rate limits on endpoints, but they do exist for performance/scalability tuning by Engineering.

thank you! We are still periodically seeing this "Connection reset by peer" error even with the Content-Length: 0 added. We are puzzled because it seems to only occur less than half of the time and not at all for some users. We are not sure if there is something that your system does not like with out sequence of calls. It is very difficult to troubleshoot and we are wondering if there is a way to receive guidance on how to hunt down the issue. We are happy to provide more details about our uses cases if that would help.

I apologize that I neglected to follow the form for providing information for questions. We are seeing a 500 Server Error "Connection reset by peer" for a call like https://wvccu.account-hq.com/login/oauth2/code/wvccu. A sample request occurred at 10:35am central September 5, 2024. clientId is 86e97b54-aea0-4b0e-8821-1b8e1ad7aa78 and x-request-id is fab8116199eab6c257e92209bbe6d1d8

Unfortunately I can't find that particular x-request-id in the logs. I'm not sure if there is typo in that value or if that's a different part of the response headers. Are you able to double-check (and ideally, provide an additional x-request-id)?

sorry what I sent to you was an internal request id. Unfortunately, due to the nature of the error we are seeing ("Connection reset by peer") the call is not completed to the Banno system so we are not receiving a response which means we are not receiving the mentioned response headers. Here is some further information for a new error today:
Request to POST https://mycentral.wvccu.org/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/token
clientId is 86e97b54-aea0-4b0e-8821-1b8e1ad7aa78
Primary redirect url is https://wvccu.account-hq.com/rewardsDashboard
Error occurred at 12:48:23.594 PM central time

The above is triggered by a call to our system as such
https://wvccu.account-hq.com/login/oauth2/code/wvccu?code=<CODE>&state=<STATE>
I omitted code and state values as they may be sensitive, if there is a way to securely share let me know. Thanks

we are wondering if there is a way to setup a call with someone from your team to help troubleshoot these issues. We are very confused about the seemingly intermittent call failures and would like to get a better understanding about why these errors are occurring.

If you're not getting an x-request-id from Banno, then it's not even reaching Banno. There's nothing we would be able to do if it's failing elsewhere in between your network and Banno.

To refresh what is happening, we started seeing “Connection Reset by peer” errors when the mentioned Banno load balancer changes were made. With research we have found that a “Connection reset by peer” error occurs when the remote server abruptly terminates the connection. Due to the intermittent nature of the error we think there is something we cannot see or explain terminating the requests before completion on your side. We want to confirm that there is nothing on your side that would terminate or refuse requests, specifically for /a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/token requests.
